# SendGrid : Free plan vs Lite plan?

Tags: smtp, sendgrid

I want to dive into SendGrid (GoDaddy SMTP is sh*ty).

But I don't understand the difference between the Free plan and Lite plan.

Of course, Lite plan is really cheap, but seems to have less features than the Free plan, which is... free.

I first told myself that the free plan most be a trial (with limited time). But the website says "No credit card needed, no expiration."

So why does somebody would prefer the lite to free?

Bonus question : The only feature I need is something like a "Send Folder", so I can be sure all emails have been sent. Does both plans have this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update: the Lite plan no longer exists.**

The Lite plan is for people that want to pay purely based on the number of emails sent. It has a limited feature set as a result. The free account has all features and has no expiration. Someone might choose Lite instead of Free because they want to send more than 12,000 emails/mo but don't need all the credits or features in the $9.95 plan.

SendGrid doesn't store any email content, so there isn't really a "sent" folder, but you can see a report of the last 7 days of email event activity by clicking on the "Activity" item in the navbar. Additionally you can have all this data pushed to you in near real-time via the [Event Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/event.html), and very soon you'll be able to pull via API as well.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot about the limit. Everything is clear to me now!

About the "Sent folder", I just realized that the feature I'm asking is "to work". With GoDaddy SMTP, it sometimes log that an email have been send, but sometime it doesn't, even if the recipient got it...